# 404 error when loading XML file

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

I have the following code to load an XML file:

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(fileName)
```

However it raises the following exception:

"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

I don't understand what's going on here. It's just an XML file - the path 'filename' is correct. It's on the computer - physically there! I can open it and edit it just fine! Also it was working fine before Christmas and the code has not changed. What on earth is going on?

Comment: So how does the _correct_ file name look like?

Comment: Seems unlikely that you'd get a 404 if you're accessing a local path. What is the value of `fileName`? Are you *certain* that this is where the error is occurring?

Comment: Just a local file. This is string for filename:

"D:\BroadviewPress20110324.xml"

Comment: I agree with Jim, this doesn't seem like where the error is occurring. I wrote a quick app that hard-codes a non-existent filename and the error I get is "
Additional information: `Could not find a part of the path 'd:\foo'.`" The fact that you're getting a 404 from a remote server make it seem the error is occurring elsewhere.

Comment: Show the xml, that error isnt from it trying to load the document. 
The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.

The web site hosting server will typically generate a "404 Not Found" web page when a user attempts to follow a broken or dead link; hence the 404 error is one of the most recognizable errors users can find on the web.

Comment: Might you 1) have enabled *external* XML Schema validation by using an `XmlReaderSettings` with [`ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  and 2) have an XML file with `xsi:schemaLocation` or `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` referring to a dead or unreachable URL?

Comment: I may well have done. I think that's the problem! Bizarre.

Comment: Wait. How do I set the settings before Load(filename)?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and turns out loading an xml document where the DTD is no longer available you get a 404 message. In our case it was because the Onix 2.1 DTD was taken out of circulation by Editeur at the end of December 2014 (as they push people to use Onix 3.0). We downloaded the 2.1 (today) via a zip file from Editeur website and then edit the XML before loading to swap DTD location to our local path...seems to work ok [still testing though].